# How to show that Hausdorff distance is a metric on the set of all compact non-empty subsets of a Polish space?

Tags: metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

> For each perfect Polish space $X$, let $H[X]$ be the set of all compact non-empty
> subsets of $X$. If $x ∈ X$ and $A ∈ H[X]$, put
> $$d(x,A) = \inf \{d(x, y) : y ∈ A\}$$
> where on the right $d$ is the distance function on $X$. The Hausdorff distance between
> two compact sets is defined by
> $$d_H(A,B) = \max \{ \sup \{d(x,B) : x ∈ A\},
> \sup\{d(y,A) : y ∈ B\}\}$$
> Prove that $d_H$ is a metric on $H[X]$.

This is an exercise on page 13, Descriptive Set Theory, Yiannis N. moschovakis(2009). I got stuck on how to show $d_H(A,B)+d_H(B,C) \ge  d_H(A,C)$.

Comment: How about distinguishing two distance functions (default distancing function and Hausdorff distance on H(X)) by different notations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $d\colon X\times X\to E^1$ be the distance in $X$ and $d_H\colon H[X]\times H[X]\to E^1$ be the Hausdorff metric on $H[X]$.

We have
$$d(a,C)\le d(a,b)+d(b,C)\le d(a,b)+d_H(B,C) $$
for all $b\in B$, so, taking $\inf_{b\in B}$, we have
$d(a,C)\le d(a,B)+d_H(B,C)$
which is $\le d_H(A,B)+d_H(B,C)$
then take $\sup_{a\in A}$, and similarly, we can show that $d(A,c)\le d_H(A,B)+d_H(B,C)$ as well.

Comment: (For the first inequality: $d(a,C)\le d(a,c)\le d(a,b)+d(b,c)$, and take $\inf_{c\in C}$ on the right hand side.)

Comment: How about distinguishing  two distance functions (default distancing function and Hausdorff distance on H(X)) by differnt notations?

Comment: I followed the notation in the original question.